# Are group boxes a deprecated UI element?

Tags: design-patterns

Back in the day, it seemed like GroupBoxes were everywhere.  Now, modern RIA kits don't even have them as basic components (Flex / GWT / Silverlight).  Is there a reason for the decline in use - are they bad practice for use in an interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you develop for Windows, I recommend that you read about group boxes in Microsoft UX Guide, which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e49820cb-954d-45ae-9cb3-1b9e8ea7fe8c), starting on page 91. There you will find guidelines on where group boxes are considered right or wrong. (See examples in the PDF.)

> - Is there more than one control in the group? If not, use a plain text
>     label instead. A rare exception is to use a group box with a single control
>     to maintain consistency with other group boxes on the same surface.
> - Are the controls related? Does showing the relationship add clarity?
>     If not, present the controls separately outside of a group box.
> - Are all the controls inside the group? If so, indicate the
>     relationship on the larger surface, such as the parent dialog box or page.
> - Can you effectively communicate the relationships without text? If so, consider using 
>     graphic elements such as backgrounds or aggregators.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if they're a bad practice but I'd say they more or less correspond to the HTML `fieldset`  attribute.
Still necessary to group / categorize options in my opinion in case of large amounts of options.
But, no, I have no idea why exactly GroupBoxes are less used...maybe because they were mainly used in WinForm-based UIs and that these have clearly declined?

;)